# Adding constants to the numerator and denominator of a fraction

Tags: inequality, fractions

I have a basic question. If $\frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{c}{d}$ and we also have $\frac{e}{f}=\frac{g}{h}$, can we say:

$$ \frac{a+e}{b+f}  \leq \frac{c+g}{d+h}$$

Basically, can we add constants to the numerator and enumerator and conclude the above inequality? Does it hold? If so, does anybody know how to prove this?
Regards,
Ali

Comment: Can any of these numbers be negative? Might not matter, but it would help to clarify your problem before people waste time working on something not intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct.
For example: $$\frac{1}{2}=0.5 < 0.66\approx \frac{1}{1.5}.$$
If you add $\frac{5}{5}=\frac{1}{1}$ you get
$$\frac{6}{7} \approx 0.85 > 0.8=\frac{2}{2.5}$$

Answer (score 1):

No, $\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{4}{2} = \frac{2}{1}$, but $\frac{1+4}{2+2} = \frac{5}{4} > \frac{3+2}{4+1}=\frac{5}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

No: $\frac{2}{1}\leq\frac{1}{\frac 12}$ (in fact, this is an equality) but $\frac{2+2}{1+1}\not\leq\frac{1+1}{\frac 12+\frac 12}$.

Comment: Isn't $\frac{2+2}{1+1}=\frac{1+1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=2$ ?